# Implementing In-App Notifications in Meteor with React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, notifications

How do I implement In-App Notifications whenever items are inserted into MongoDB collections in React with Meteor? Upon clicking the icon, I want the number to reset back to zero.
[image]

Comment: There are multiple way, but the meteor react tutorial provides at least 90% of the solution. Can you show how far you got? It will be easier to help once some code is there.